# Google Sheets dynamic currency conversion by date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have created [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r2_BklX19pQ3EIcSZlXeKzhoa92n3UNkj3ULOSOaEOs/edit?usp=sharing) sheet to manage my personal finances. However, I would like use a query or formula in the 'TB" sheet so that it calculates the exchange rate from the 'Exchange Rates' sheet and gives me correct output based on the date and currency filter. The trick is that is shall have to lookup the transaction currency and date in the 'Data' sheet and give the correct calculation in the 'TB' sheet. A similar calculation would apply in the sheets after that but without the date filter. The difference is that in case of the currency selection being blank, it would display the transaction currency. How can I achieve this?

Comment: a vlookup(0 or index() with match() - many examples on here.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply. However, I need a specific formula since I'm not too technical. I wouldn't understand how to navigate through all the posts to come up with one.